# How about adding "ancient-Iran" tag?

Tags: feature-request, tagging

I found some questions about or related to ancient-Iran and think it can be an appropriate guide for users who are searching this category of questions. I don't have enough reputations to create it myself. Could you add it yourself?

Persia is a synonym for Iran not a synonym for ancient-Iran because it is a name and maybe many people who come here in a willing to find for ancient-Iran questions cannot find it and Persia makes them confused as it refers to the old name of Iran not the whole ancient history behind this name. As you know Persia refers to a part of ancient Iran from Sassanaid empire and not refer to some hundred years before it.

**I added ancient-Iran and suggested the Persia as a synonym of Iran. It seems more rational.**

Comment: No idea? can you? cannot you? :)

Comment: Should the tag be "persia" instead? (or make this an alias)

Comment: Persia is the old name however I love it but we want to know about the ancient history of Iran, the land which we know it Iran nowadays. Most people know something about Iran but not about Persia.

Comment: What do you mean by "know something about Iran but not about Persia"? That the name Persia is not commonly recognized?

Comment: Yes! Many people do not know where Persia is because Persia is its ancient name . Now it is Iran.

Comment: Then I disagree. F.e. all children in Polish schools are taught about "Persia", not "ancient Iran". Together with Persian language, Persian carpet and "Prince of Persia" it gives more knowledge than people here have about modern Iran. The term "ancient Iran" sounds very artificial here. It's hard to imagine a Pole coming here and searching for "ancient-iran" while at the same time easy to imagine one searching for "persia" tag.

Comment: Sorry but it seems you didn't get the idea. Persia is a synonym of Iran not a synonym for ancient-Iran. If there is a very wrong method of teaching to some children in a country in the Europe it doesn't mean it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see to add a new tag is to add it to already existing question. So if you help me and provide a link to such question, I'll add it for you.

Comment: It is here:http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/7845/what-does-the-anointed-of-the-lord-mean

Comment: I've added it, using small letters (ancient-iran), as every tag on the site follows the same rule. It would be nice if you support a short description of the tag over here: http://history.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1774 - somebody with higher privileges will accept it later.

Comment: Ok I will do! ;)